# Determine whether the trigger is created successfully or not using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs

I want to determine programically whether the trigger is created successfully but even an unsuccessful trigger brings out a unique id and it seems to be created.

```
//this will show 0
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
showAlert(triggers.length); //define showAlert

var dt = new Date(2015,03,03,20,10) // create past date or feb 31
//Month index starts from 0 i.e. Jan =0,Feb=1... So on
 var ret = ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').timeBased().at(dt).create()

showAlert(ret.getUniqueId()); //will display ID for sure

//this will show 1
var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
showAlert(triggers.length); //define showAlert
```

But actually the trigger isn't created

Comment: ``at()`` is used only one time. And a trigger cannot be created for the past time. Although it has a ID, the trigger had been done. So the trigger has already been removed. If you modify ``dt`` to ``var dt = new Date(2018,03,03,20,10)``, you can see the trigger at current trigger list.

Comment: Oh no, I know the above fact. My question is how will I determine whether the trigger is valid or not programically. It will not throw error, it only deletes the trigger.

Comment: I'm sorry the misunderstanding. In your sample script, the information of a trigger created for the past time can be retrieved. But actually such trigger doesn't work. So after the script for creating the past trigger was finished, when ``getProjectTriggers()`` is used, the length is zero. At this time, I thought that the time might be necessary to remove the past trigger. So I put ``Utilities.sleep(1000)`` between ``var ret =`` and ``var triggers =`` of your script. After put it, the trigger information of the past time disappeared. Will this lead to the solution?

Comment: Is using sleep for 1 sec reliable, what if there are network or other factors affecting delays ?

Comment: Such delays appear in the case without sleep. If sleep isn't used, the trigger information sometimes disappears. At that time, it is considered that the information is deleted by the delay. But for a lot of cases, the information can be seen. When sleep is used, even if it's 1 second, the information always disappears. I think that since ``sleep`` absolutely carries out a time set by user on Google, it always disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to check to see if the entered date has passed? And only set the trigger if it has not passed.

```
var dt = new Date(2015,03,03,20,10) // create past date or feb 31
//Month index starts from 0 i.e. Jan =0,Feb=1... So on
if( dt > new Date()){  //new Date() gives current date
 var ret = ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction').timeBased().at(dt).create()
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Jack. Good